"Kilogram" confusion: If you weigh a stationary object in "kilograms" and divide the result by about $9.8$, does that tell you the mass of the object?
Update: I appreciate all of the answers very much
In a way, I'm delighted to find that such a simple question has generated so much disagreement (most of which can be attributed to issues with wording, to be fair). It goes to show that even relatively simple things in physics must be thought about with the proper degree of nuance and carefully worded to avoid potential confusion.
To summarize what I've learned (the most important of which is point #3):

When I observe a scale reading which is in kilograms, I must multiply by the local gravity (in $\operatorname{ms^{-2}}$) to find the force exerted on the scale in Newtons ($\operatorname{kgms^{-2}}$)
Likewise, if I read a number on the scale which is in pounds then
the "pound" does not refer to pound-force but instead to the
unit for mass known as simply the "pound"
A use of terminology which I think is helpful: scales measure
weight (force exerted on the scale), but the reading given as
a number on the scale is the mass required to exert that much force
on the scale at the location at which the scale was most recently
calibrated.
A balance, on the other hand, lacks the sophisticated digital technology to automatically convert from force to mass, and can only determine whether or not the force exerted by the non-standard mass is the same as the force exerted by the standard masses. Thus, if you only know the weights of the standard masses you're using but not their actual masses, then in order to determine the object's mass, you must do the math yourself, dividing the determined weight by the local gravity in order to calculate the object's mass. Or, if you already know the total mass of the standard masses balancing out your non-standard mass, then that's obviously the mass of the non-standard mass.

I think we can all agree that balances have no idea how many moles of what elements comprise the non-standard mass, nor what the respective molar masses are. Likewise, we can all agree that the technology involved in a balance is nowhere near as mechanically sophisticated as the technology involved in an accelerometer. This is why I'd rather not think of balances in terms of mass. Yes, the numbers printed on the standard masses are masses (as opposed to weights) but the mechanism by which balances determine mass is one that involves a direct comparison of the forces (weights) exerted. It takes a complete moron to believe that a balance would not work equally well on Earth as on the moon (ignoring wind currents on Earth, of course), and this is not at all what I believe.

I'm glad I asked this, because my whole life I've assumed that the reading on a scale is the force exerted on the scale (weight) and not the mass required to exert that much force under the local gravity at the most recent location of calibration. This makes my memories of finding masses in chemistry by using scales (and no subsequent math) make a lot more sense.
It seems I've underestimated the efforts that the inventors of our modern digital technology have gone through to make determinations of mass entirely math-free.

Original question
I'm not exactly sure whether or not modern scales and modern food scales take the (kilo)gram versus (kilo)gram-force distinction into account.
I have a faint memory of measuring mass in grams in my chemistry class as a teenager. I don't believe we ever had to divide by $9.8$ after placing objects on the scale, so this leads me to think that perhaps modern scales and modern food scales already take into account the kilogram versus kilogram-force distinction.
So my question is: do modern (especially digital, I suppose) scales automatically make the adjustment to convert from force (weight) to mass? Or is the number on the scale a measure of force (weight) which must be divided by $g$ to obtain the mass?

There's a lot of talk (below) about the distinction between "scales" and "balances." IMO, that's an obsolete distinction. All weighing instruments measure force. Some weighing instruments (sometimes called "balances") directly compare the weight of the unknown mass to the weight of a known mass. Others ("scales") compare the weight of the unknown to some other known force. According to that nomenclature, the most precise modern instruments are scales that have been carefully calibrated to convert the force measurement to the equivalent mass. The best modern instruments are so precise...

...that, in order to achieve their best possible accuracy, they are calibrated in the exact location where they will be used. If you move the scale to a different location, you are presumed to have moved it into the influence of a different gravitational anomaly, and so you re-calibrate it, using a set of known masses, before you rely on it to give accurate mass measurements.

I think there must be a moving gravitational anomaly under my house. There is no other possible explanation for why my weight has been increasing since Christmas.

I don't know whether or not it's an advisable policy to upvote comments just for being funny, but I'll have you know I indeed got a nice chuckle out of this :)

While I'm here, I'd also like to say that Solomon Slow gave my favorite explanation, with controlgroup's explanation coming in second place by a small margin. Overall, though, I appreciate everyone's answer and I feel as though I learned what I needed to from taking into account the totality of all the various answers

In my opinion, item 4 is incorrect.  A balance compares a known mass to an unknown mass.  This means that balances determine mass, not weight.  I other words, if you weighed yourself on the moon, you would weigh 1/6 as much as you do on earth.  However, if you used a balance on the moon, you would STILL get your true mass as the answer because that 1/6 surface gravity is affecting both the known mass and your mass by the same ratio.

@DavidWhite what about my caveat "Or, if you already know the total mass of the standard masses balancing out your non-standard mass, then that's your answer". My point with item 4 is only that balances do not perform the calculation necessary to convert force to mass, the idea being that scales have this inbuilt digital computational feature that balances lack

That said, I do understand now that standard masses are indeed masses and not weights, so the caveat I gave applies to the rule rather than the exception

@DavidWhite My answer agrees that a balance determines mass not weight, but I do like your clear intuitive  demonstration of why that is the case.

I think we can all agree that balances have no idea how many moles of what elements comprise the non-standard mass, nor what the respective molar masses are. This is why I'd rather not think of balances in terms of mass. Yes, the numbers printed on the standard masses are masses (as opposed to weights) but the mechanism by which balances determine mass is one that involves a direct comparison of the forces (weights) exerted. It takes a complete moron to believe that a balance would not work equally well on Earth as on the moon, and this is not at all what I believe.

In my opinion a balance measures the difference between two forces (weights).  If you tried to use a balance in space, it would give no result.  Thus it is not a direct measurement of mass (unlike, say, a spring with an accelerometer that directly measures $F/a$)

Yes, that's why I used David's example of the moon as opposed to the vacuum of space. And that's also why I greatly prefer to think of balances in terms of weight instead of mass. Clearly, balances have no concept of moles, elements, or molar mass, nor do they use something as sophisticated as an accelerometer.

IMO an instrument measures whatever it is designed and calibrated to measure in the intended environment of the instrument. For example, if you want to measure the instantaneous velocity of a missile, you could attach an accelerometer to a missile with a cpu that integrates the acceleration of the missile since launch and then display the calculated velocity. If you want to measure the orientation of the missile in space, you could use gyroscopes and digital output to indicate orientation, but the operating principle of the gyroscope is that it responds to torque.

There are several wrong answers here, and a few that are worded in a misleading way.
A scale always measures force.  The measurement is a force, which can be thought of in units of Newtons or pounds (pounds-force, if we want to call it that).
For proof of that, take your scale, stand it up sideways in a doorway, leaning up against one side of the doorframe.  Then, pushing against the other side of the door frame, push on the scale as hard as you can.  Observe that the numbers go up as force is applied -- no mass is actually on top of the scale while doing this.
The only way for a scale to provide you a mass is if you use it in a particular way (standing stationary on it with no outside forces), and if you know the acceleration of gravity at your location.  Once you have this, you can calculate the mass on top of the scale by dividing the measured force by this acceleration of gravity.  If precision is not an issue, using a standard value for this acceleration such as 9.81 m/s^2 is sufficient.
If you go to the moon, the scale will still measure force.  Your weight, the force due to gravity observed when not accelerating, is 1/6 what it is on Earth.  A scale will measure force, and calculate mass.  If it is not programmed to be aware that it is on the moon, it may still try to use 9.81m/s^2.  If it does, the mass it reports will be 1/6 of your actual mass.  This is because it measured a force, and used the wrong acceleration of gravity when computing a mass.
A balance is different.  It only provides a meaningful result when used properly with two masses, and no external forces.  Because both sides of the balance receive a force proportional to the acceleration of gravity the measurement permits computing the mass of the object (relative to the known mass on the other side) in a way which is independent to gravity -- the force of gravity cancels out in both cases.
As an aside, I had to word that last paragraph carefully.  Balances do not directly measure mass.  If anything, they measure deflection -- how far system is out of balance.  But when the balance is aligned, we  indirectly measure mass.  The difference between the balance and the scale is that, in the case of a balance, the effects of varying accelerations of gravity cancel out perfectly such that we can say we measure mass (if indirectly)
The no external forces is important.  Balances often are put inside sealed glass containers to prevent wind currents from imparting a force and disturbing the balance.
In SI units, spring scales provide numbers in kilograms, even though they actually measured Newtons, because that was the number people wanted.  Balances came before spring scales, so we were already used to working in masses.  In English units, pounds is technically a unit of force.  The "slug" is the English unit of mass, but it is almost unheard of.  Typically we hear of "pounds-mass" which is a fancy way of saying "however much mass it takes to apply a force of 1 pound at the standard altitude (standard acceleration of gravity."  For most humans, these are interchangeable, and "pound" is both a unit of force and mass to them.
Some spring scales or digital scales permit calibration.  In calibration, one puts a known mass on the scale and the scale uses the force it applies to calibrate an acceleration of gravity for the current location (and to correct for any other inaccuracies in the measurement system).  Once calibrated properly, the scale can read in mass correctly, but that's only a reading.  It still measured in force, but with the calibrations, it knows the correct acceleration of gravity to apply.  Were you to take that scale to the moon, and calibrate it on the moon, it would give you your correct mass when you stood on it.  Still measuring a force, but the conversion factor would have been correctly computed for the circumstances.
For completeness: I have used balance here in the traditional sense of two plates and a beam between them.  When the beam is level, the two masses are equal.  If you dig deeper into metrology, you will find that balances are just any measurement device that is designed to measure when at some balanced state.  You adjust one side or the other until it is balanced.  A traditional balance measures when the deflection of the beam is 0.  A Kibble Balance is a balance that measures weight, balancing it against an electric current providing an opposing force.  Causing potential confusion, the Kibble Balance is how we define the kilogram.  Hiding in this definition is that one uses a gravimeter in the same lab to very precisely compute the acceleration of gravity.  In this sense, the Kibble Balance acts more like a fancy scale (the fanciest ever created), but it is called a balance because the method one operates it requires balancing two effects.

In a way, I'm delighted to find that such a simple question has generated so much disagreement. It goes to show that even relatively simple things in physics must be thought about with the proper degree of nuance and carefully worded to avoid potential confusion

Scales are usually tuned to tell you the mass, not the weight. The weight would be measured in newtons.
Note that some types of scale, i.e. spring scales, often do measure in newtons (weight). To obtain kilograms from newtons of weight, you divide by local gravity, which is usually about $9.8\,\mathrm{m}\,\mathrm{s}^{-2}$ unless you’re doing something (or in a vehicle of some sort that’s doing something) really cool. Scales will always indicate what they’re measuring, kilograms or newtons, unless they’re really low-quality scales in which case you shouldn’t be using them.

I think this answer confuses the OP.  Scales never measure mass.  As you correctly state, they may tell you a mass, but it is not the thing they measured.  If you took a scale to the moon, it would claim that your mass is 1/6 what it was on the Earth, but that would not actually be a true measurement.  Your weight would be 1/6, and the scale would mistakenly apply the wrong acceleration of gravity for the moon when converting to kilograms.

@CortAmmon A digital spring scale could incorporate an accelerometer and divide by its reading instead of a constant. I don't know whether there are any that do.

@benrg That is true.  This gets into metrology, and my answer dabbles in it, but I think we don't see such combined measurement devices for calibration.  From a metrology perspective, it would be better to have two devices (a scale and a gravimeter) which are calibrated as separate events because it makes the errors easier to understand.  Also, one gravimeter could support measurements from multiple scales (even in the case of the Kibble balance, the only requirement appears to have been that the gravimeter was in the same lab)

Manufacturer of devices which measure "mass" do differentiate between balances and scales.
A balance consists of a pivoted beam with the object whose mass is to be found on one side and a set of standard masses on the other.
If the arm of the beam are of equal length the when the beam is balanced the mass of the object is equal to the mass of the standard masses on the other side of the beam.
Thus, although this is a device which compares forces (weights) on either side of the beam the variation in the local acceleration of free fall either side of the balance is negligible and so a balance does directly measure mass.
A scale is a device which measures a force and in particular the object's "weight", $mg$, where $m$ is the mass of the object and $g$ the local value of the acceleration of free fall.
A scale is calibrated either in newtons or much more frequently in kilogrammes, grammes, pounds, ounces, etc.
When the calibration is done in units of mass, in effect the local value of the acceleration of free fall is used to make the calibration and this means that the scales only measure the correct value of mass when they are used at a place where the local value of the acceleration of free fall is the same.
Thus, for a scale originally calibrated in units of mass at a place where $g=9.81\,\rm m/s^2$, the reading of mass on the scale will be too high at one of the geographic poles where $g\approx 9.83 \,\rm m/s^2$ and the reading of mass on the scale will be too low on the equator where $g\approx 9.78 \,\rm m/s^2$.
If necessary, modern digital scales can be recalibrated at a particular location using standard masses.


"Kilogram" confusion: If you weigh a stationary object in "kilograms"
and divide the result by about $9.8$, does that tell you the mass of
the object?

No. If the scales are calibrated in kilograms, it tells you the mass of the object, and you would have to multiply by $9.8$ to find out the corresponding force in Newtons.
When asked what our weight is, we might say $75 \ \text{kg}$ or $165 \ \text{pounds}$, but this is a misuse of language because we are actually quoting our mass (but everyone does it).

When I observe a scale reading which is in kilograms, I must multiply
by the local gravity (in $\text{ms}^{-2}$) to find the force exerted on the
scale in Newtons ($\text{kg m s}^{-2}$)

Agree.

Likewise, if I read a number on the scale which is in pounds then the
"pound" does not refer to pound-force but instead to the unit of mass
known as simply the "pound"

Agree.

A use of terminology which I think is helpful: scales measure weight
(force exerted on the scale), but the reading is given as a number on the
scale is the mass required to exert that much force on the scale at
the location at which the scale was most recently calibrated.

Agree.

A balance, on the other hand, can only determine how much force is
exerted by the non-standard mass you're weighing. Thus, if you know
the weights of the standard masses you're using but not their actual
masses, then in order to determine the object's mass, you must do the
math yourself, dividing the determined weight by the local gravity in
order to calculate the object's mass. Or, if you already know the
total mass of the standard masses balancing out your non-standard
mass, then that's your answer.

Here, we are talking about balance scales. The type the Statue of Liberty has in her hand. Normally standard 'weights' will have a number and units stamped on it, like $1 \ \text{kg}$ or $5 \ \text{lb}$, and that is the mass, and if the balance balances, then your unknown object will have the same mass as the standard 'weight' on the other side. Similarly, the 'weights' stamped on barbells in gyms are usually masses and will usually have units of $\text{kg}$ or $\text{lb}$. It is very rare to find standard 'weights' calibrated in Newtons or $\text{kg}$-force.
Spring balances with a hook are usually calibrated in mass units, but occasionally they will be calibrated in kilogram-force or Newtons for specialised lab or school use, in which case the indication should be divided by $9.8$ if you want to know the mass of the suspended object.

Scales measure mass. This should be clear if you first weigh an object on a spring (or digital) scale, and then on on a balance. Both give the same result, but with the balance gravity acts on both arms, so it cancels out.
EDIT
The following offers some clarification after the comments.
All scales are calibrated to show mass, regardless of how they operate. To convert that mass into force, multiply it by $9.8ms^{-2}$. That force is measured in Newtons. $1N$ is the force required to accelerate a mass of $1kg$ at $1ms^{-2}$.
Scales are calibrated for a 1g environment, like earth. On another planet, a balance (which compares the forces on both arms) will still show the same mass, but spring scales (or digital) actually measure force, and hence will show a different result, depending on the local gravity. In orbit, neither will work.
To clarify the confusion between pounds-mass and pounds-force, read this question:
https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/pound-force-lbf-vs-pound-mass-lbm#4155

So if I change the scale to measure in pounds, do I have to multiply by $g$ in order to find out the pound-force and thus find out the actual weight?

@SimonM, what would be the difference between the the reading in pounds and the "actual weight"?   What is meant by "actual weight" here?    Most would suppose that a reading in pounds is the actual weight.

By actual weight I mean the force that the object exerts on the scale. Are you saying that when you switch from kilograms to pounds then the scale switches from measuring mass to measuring force?

Almost all scales indirectly measure force (by spring displacement or by a load cell).      You can squeeze them to see that it's always measuring force.
They then convert that force measurement to an equivalent mass in KG.
Technically pounds are already a measure of force, but in common usage, no one cares.

Ok this is very good to know. To summarize: when I read a measurement in kilograms, I must multiply by the local gravity to find the force exerted on the scale. On the other hand, if I read a measurement in pounds then I'm already reading the force exerted on the scale and do not have to do any calculation at all.

Mass is measured in grams ($g$); weight is a force, measured in Newtons ($N$). If the scale is in pounds, it is still measuring mass. Remember the equivalence between the spring scales and a balance; that is as true in imperial systems as in metric. The only difference is that the imperial system is confusing because the same unit is used for mass and force.

@hdhondt that clears things up very well. I'm no longer confused. I'm glad I asked this question; my whole life I've been assuming that the readings on scales are meant to be the force exerted on the scale (e.g. weight, not mass). I never would have imagined that the reading on the scale is actually the mass

This answer is wrong.  Scales do not measure mass.  They always measure force.  They may provide you a readout in kilograms, using a conversion that assumes some pre-defined acceleration of gravity (i.e. 9.8 m/s^2).  But the actual thing measured was a force.

I'm glad that my point #3 is receiving some validation. I truly think more care should be taken to properly distinguish between a measurement and a readout

If the units on the scale are kilograms, then it's measuring kilograms.
It is rare but possible to find a scale that directly measures Newtons.   For such a scale you could divide the reading by 9.8 to find the mass (in kilograms) that would produce an equivalent force.
10 N ~ 1 kg

I believe you meant "divide the reading by 9.8 to find the mass"?

You meant divide, right? You said multiply - but $F=ma$ and $m=\frac{F}{a}=\frac{F}{g}$.

Exactly - your answer says multiply instead of divide.
