Does the different strength of gravity at varying heights affect the forces within a suspended or standing object?
If there was a very tall object suspended just above the ground the force of gravity acting on a nominal sized section of it would be higher near the bottom than at the top. Would this increase the tension within the object?
Now stand the object on the ground. The force within the object has changed to compression. What would the contribution of different gravity strengths at different heights do to the total force of compression within the object? Ignore effects from rotation of the earth.
PS this is not homework.
Edit. How could the contribution to compression and tension from the tidal effect be calculated? I guess they would be the same but opposite for same object?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force

Gravity doesn't change much with altitude. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkEFrwkAQhe%5F7Kx4rlCSVGDcmtmKkLQi9FEouvUjLNlk3S%2DOqmzEo0v9eEqXg8X0w37wZzjmW0lEF7WRr6IQ7qKaQO4VW1dvC0IkBwIczRMri%2D4T3N4jcWA0RiUkYpeF4wjjnYCxHhjSeJuFknIppHKcqxuAqlmS2VtZwsjSHhmlkeAwfojRNMEBD0pbSlf8lGHsylpSTBbFSrfHl0ZGyV9rUL9ujx%2DdVvLhpPR9V8YL7QwZUmcdlTYYOpYL3s%5FH5EOMo8v1Zf4hDhhz3HYoQoOrhHhm8HCM4H0EA0UPdddwjgO7jzhlL3po%5FF4WqlevvWVlIZDhrPQuT9S82o%2DZTdGB%5FyZr7%5FWzb%2DUWn0giuS6IwufGu7PL27yuLczsLxcXLffYH0wN2OQ==&lang=sage

@PM2Ring Not so much on earth, but an earth-mass black hole would have quite the gradient.

@CristobolPolychronopolis  There is a tide. Also "Neutron Star".

@Cristobol True, but an Earth-mass black hole has a Schwarzschild radius of ~8.870056 mm, and its tidal force at 1 km is strong enough to snap a 1 m long steel bar in freefall.

@PM2Ring My point exactly.  While the gradient is usually negligible when looking at height above the Earth's surface (but still in the atmosphere) that approximation is not a universal option.

Yes, the tension put on objects due to the imbalance of gravity across their volumes is called the tidal force.
The tidal force puts into tension objects that are large and/or near strong gravitational fields (for very weak fields tidal forces can become negligible). In fact, it’s the cause of moons breaking up when they get too close to their planetary primaries, the heating of moon-planet systems, and moons always having one side facing their planetary primary.
It primarily affects very large objects, which is why it’s most often observed in things like moons and binary planetoids, but it still exists for smaller objects too.

Indeed, tidal forces are usually only meaningful for large objects stretching a long way across a gravitational field that changes slowly through space, since gravitational fields tend to be mostly invariant on a small scale. For the rarer (usually theoretical) case of a small object in a rapidly changing field (like a person falling into a black hole), the term "spaghettification" becomes relevant.

If you work in a cartesian coordinate system around the center of mass (or maybe gravity--they are different) of your object, in a non rotating planetary field at distance $R$ from the planet's center, you have, for small displacements in the $z$ direction:
$$ \vec g(z) = -g_0\frac{R^2}{(R+z)^2}\hat z \approx
-g_0\frac{\hat z}{1 + \frac{2z}R} = \approx
-g_0\hat z (1-2\frac z R)$$
$g_0$ is the usual Newtonian gravity.
while small displacements in any transverse direction (here, $x$):
$$ \vec g(x) = -g_0(\hat z + \frac x R\hat x)$$
so, for a displacement:
$$ \vec r = x\hat x + y\hat y + z \hat z$$
the field strength is:
$$ \vec g(r) = -g_0\hat z + {\bf T} \vec r $$
with
$$ {\bf T} = \frac{g_0}R
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & +2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
is a tidal tensor. It applies a longitudinal ($z$) tension, and transverse ($x, y$) compression.
Since:
$$ {\rm Tr}({\bf T})=0 $$
the stress is volume preserving (or, the pressure is zero).
Note also, that in spherical form, the tidal tensor is proportional to $Y_{l=2}^{m=0}(\theta, \phi)$, so it induces a cylindrically symmetric quadrupole moment strain: bulging at the ends, with 1/2 as much compression around 2 dimension around the equator. It's very geometric.

I think your question supposes the wrong model of what is going on. For a suspended object the tension at the point of suspension must counter the total weight of the object, which can be found by integrating the (varying gravitational acceleration) times unit mass over the object. Similarly, when it is instead placed on the ground the compression (negative tension) must counter the total weight of the object, which is given by the same integral. The fact that the gravitational acceleration varies from place to place is taken into account in the integral, but the variation as such does not cause any tension or compression.
[I abuse of the occasion to mention a somewhat related thought I had the other day. For athletes in weight-controlled categories of sport, their weight category could vary as a function of the gravitational acceleration at the sporting venue, unless the weight limits for the categories are accordingly tweaked. Do organisers of these events take this into consideration? I could find no evidence of this. This is of course not a physics question...]

The variation in gravitational acceleration is pretty negligible for athletes. But the variation in available oxygen at altitude is an important consideration.

@PM2Ring I was not wondering about effect on gravity on the sport itself, but about the fact that an athlete (in judo say) could be prohibited from competing in a given weight category due to slightly excessive weight, whereas the same athlete would be accepted in that category at a different venue, where gravity is less strong. Variations in weight could be small (less than half a percent) but that still could push someone out of their weight category.

Scales are usually calibrated to show mass, not weight. See this recent question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/825759/123208

https://mathstodon.xyz/@johncarlosbaez/113155869072460093
